# Visual Studio 2010 Property Help

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, properties

In Visual Studios 2005 and 2008 one can see a short sentence or two describing each property in the Forms Designer.  This doesn't seem to be there with Visual Studio 2010.  Is this an option that I have yet to turn on?  Or is there something I just don't understand about the Help system?  I would like quick access to information about the properties I'm work with, as in WPF they are very different that what I'm used to working with WinForms.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean.   With WPF there is nothing at the bottom of the properties window to explain the property you are currently editing.  With winforms, kyndigs answer is right, but that's not your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 does not provide the same convenient property descriptions as Visual Studio 2008.  I'm sure there is a good reason for this, though it is very annoying.  Those property descriptions were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It should show at the bottom of the Properties window.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2010, it is not!  Correction-- it is with some obscure properties like the Settings I've added to the project.